# Difference between socketChannel.register() and key.interestOps()?

Tags: java, nio

What's the deference   between [`SocketChannel.register()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#register%28java.nio.channels.Selector,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29)  and   [`SelectionKey.interestOps()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#interestOps%28%29)?

In the echo NIO server found [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556901/java-high-load-nio-tcp-server),
for every key that is accepted, a register is called for a read op.  Then once a message is read, the register is called again for a write op.  However, after writing a message, rather than registering another read op it calls `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)`.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`register()` will lose or change the key attachment, and possibly return a new `SelectionKey` altogether: it isn't specified. Use `interestOps()` in this situation.

Comment: thanks - just to clarify as I am new to the non blocking model, is this the write pattern for an echo server?  Accept connection, call socketChannel.register() to register new socket for reading, in read operation use key.interestOps()? to register write operation and in write operation use key.interestOps()? to once more listen for read?  So basically the socketChannel.register() is only called once per connection to register the new socket and from then on further operations are controlled using key.interestOps() to control reads/writes?

Comment: No. A channel is almost always ready for writing, so you should just write, with caveats. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20967805/207421).